# -[__NSCFArray bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I have saved the array of my products in the user default as below:

```
  NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [userDefault setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:plans] forKey:@"plans"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and read the default as below:

```
    NSArray *plans;
    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"plans"];
    if (data != nil)
    {
        plans = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    }
```

But sometimes my app getting crashed with **-[__NSCFArray bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance** while calling `unarchiveObjectWithData` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you must have stored an NSArray into NSUserDefaults instead of archived data. Have you tried clearing your user defaults and trying again?